# Git error (warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1, etc..)

Tags: bash, github, git-bash, git-for-windows, git-shell

Wanted to learn git, so i donwloaded it and wrote some things.
When I opened it today, it "crashed" my windows 10 and then showed a few tenths of errors. I tried to work in visual studio code, but when i write some git command like `ls-la` it shows me that it doesnt not recognize this command. It is probably that i am in powershell terminal.

Here are some pics:

**I open the git**

[image]

**Windows crashes because git consumes too much ram**

[image]

**I try to close the git but this window pops out**
[image]

**And git after a while loads like normal**

[image]

**ERROR MESSAGES:**

```
/usr/bin/bash: warning: shell level (1000) too high, resetting to 1
      0 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68440 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1040411 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68468 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (68508) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   5744 [main] bash (68508) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3233984 [main] bash 4187 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68508 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 55808 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (55876) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    421 [main] bash (55876) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1188122 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 55876 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (56044) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    600 [main] bash (56044) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3381615 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56044 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (56208) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    419 [main] bash (56208) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
7600315 [main] bash 4188 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56208 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (56728) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    455 [main] bash (56728) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4189 dofork: child -1 - forked process 56728 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (57056) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    390 [main] bash (57056) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4190 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57056 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (57196) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1304 [main] bash (57196) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1377111 [main] bash 4190 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57196 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (57420) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1044 [main] bash (57420) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57420 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (57688) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
   1326 [main] bash (57688) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
1272058 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 57688 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3288717 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - forked process 58096 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7295303 [main] bash 4191 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe', errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (59256) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    474 [main] bash (59256) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4192 dofork: child -1 - forked process 59256 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1041835 [main] bash 4192 dofork: child -1 - forked process 59464 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4196 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68460 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      1 [main] bash (68516) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    352 [main] bash (68516) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4197 dofork: child -1 - forked process 68516 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (63444) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    308 [main] bash (63444) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 63444 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1038461 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 63756 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (64068) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    423 [main] bash (64068) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3258595 [main] bash 4207 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64068 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64404 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
1036326 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 44524 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
3060575 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - forked process 64712 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC000012D, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
7078056 [main] bash 4209 dofork: child -1 - CreateProcessW failed for 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe', errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (44944) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    418 [main] bash (44944) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 44944 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
      0 [main] bash (52852) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    496 [main] bash (52852) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
3150088 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 52852 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (22312) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    349 [main] bash (22312) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
7943439 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 22312 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (19268) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    344 [main] bash (19268) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
13178493 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 19268 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
      0 [main] bash (23236) C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - MEM_COMMIT failed, Win32 error 1455
    379 [main] bash (23236) cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to bash.exe.stackdump
21902642 [main] bash 4249 dofork: child -1 - forked process 23236 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
/c/Users/GRZEG/.bashrc: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

GRZEG@DESKTOP-25LL6A3 MINGW64 ~
$
```

I try to use vscode but as I said, the `ls -la` command is not recognized

[image]

**bash.bashrc file**
[image]

Comment: With the screendumps I can not read everything you posted. You must have a loop somewhere: a login script that calls the login-script. Do you have a `$HOME/.bashrc` file? Rename it to `.bashrc.bak` and see if that helps. And what is `/etc/profile/git.prompt.sh` doing?

Comment: im using windows so i dont have $HOME. But even if i find .bashrc and rename to .bashrc.bak, it rename itself to .bashrc and still doesnt work :/
And I have no idea what it is doing haha

Comment: Look for files in `/c/users/grzeg`, something starting with a dot. When i write `bash` in my `.bashrc` file, each time a bash shell is opened, that shell will execute `.bashrc` and that file will start another `bash`, that will start another ` .bashrc` that will ...

Comment: Wow, that work, thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First a comment)
When the `$HOME/.bashrc` (in your case `/c/users/grzeg/.bashrc`) calls bash, than each time a bash shell is opened, that shell will execute .bashrc and that file will start another bash, that will start another  `.bashrc` that will ...
So first take away that endless loop by renaming `/c/users/grzeg/.bashrc` to `/c/users/grzeg/.bashrc.org`